# How to implement Gaussian filter of kernel size 3

Tags: python, image-processing, gaussian, gaussianblur

Can someone please help me in computing the Gaussian filter values? I have seen other related posts but was unable to figure out the proper solution.
I have the 2D gaussian equation:

```
def gauss2d(x,y,sigma):
    return (1/(2*math.pi*math.pow(sigma,2)))*math.exp(-0.5*
                           (pow(x,2)+pow(y,2))/pow(sigma,2))
```

I want to figure out how to compute the elements of a 3x3 or a 5x5 Gaussian filter with discrete values

Comment: A 3x3 filter can never be a Gaussian. https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695

Answer (score 1):

This implementation has a slight difference of, when normalization is applied, but it's just a minor thing.

```
def gaussian(sigma,Y,X):
    kernel = np.zeros((Y,X))
    ax = range(X) - np.floor(X/2)
    ay = range(Y) - np.floor(Y/2)
    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(ax,ay)
    kernel = np.exp(-0.5 * (np.square(xx) + np.square(yy)))/np.square(sigma)
    kernel = kernel/np.sum(kernel)
    return kernel 

print(np.sum(gaussian(0.3,5,5)))
```

Comment: I want to know the implementation of th kernel filter, like for 3x3  i.e. 1/16[[1,2,1],[2,4,2],[1,2,1]]

Comment: what do you mean by the implementation? the above-mentioned code is the implementation.